# Excel Macro Issue

Tags: excel

Hello anyone that can help.

I have two columns. the code is below. All I am doing is graphing in a macro. First when I select the columns while recording I get a normal graph with one line. The X axis is referring to column B and the Y axis is referring to column C. However, once I am done recording and I press crtl + o the macro runs, but two graphs appear. The two columns didn't "sync" with one another and they individually graphed it. How is it creating two graphs from a recorded macro where I only made one graph?

```
' Macro3 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+o
'
    Range("B1:C16").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'Sheet1'!$B$1:$B$16")
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatterSmooth
```

Comment: 2 graphs as in 2 new graphs, making three graphs altogether, or 2 graphs as in the original when you recorded plus 1 new graph?

Comment: **How is that possible?** You recorded a macro that makes a chart based on data in `B1:C16`. Every time you run this macro, it will create another chart based on this same data.  What exactly are you trying to do, and what do you mean by "The two columns didn't "sync" with one another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess what you want is this maybe?

```
Sub Macro1()
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatterSmooth
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Sheet1!$B$1:$B$16"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=Sheet1!$C$1:$C$16"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked like a charm. I apologize if i wasnt clear in my question to anyone who had trouble understanding what i was asking. Im real new to VB. Thank you for your time.